# In Which Order Excecutes a UI5 Application and How Differs the Execution Between a Stand Alone and Fiori Launchpad Embedded UI5 Application?

Tags: sapui5

could someone please let me know the order of execution of below files in both fiori application and stand alone app(which is not configured in the fiori launchpad)

1.index.html

2.component.js

3.manifest.js

4.main controller

5.main view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### stand alone ui5 application:

start of the application (**index.html**)

load ui5 resources

index's bootstrap loads component (**component.js**)

component loads descriptor (**manifest.json**)

component creates manifest's models

execute component's init function

component's init function executes parent ui component's init function

parent ui component's init function creates manifest's router

parent ui component's init function creates manifest's root view **(main.view.*)**

root view creates root control

component's init function intialises router

router create other necessary views

each view loads corresponding controller **(main.controller.*)**

each controller executes init function

router places views in root control

models are available in the views

view's binding's evaluation

retrieve model data

---

### fiori launchpad embedded ui5 application:

same same but different. just omit the first step, switch the order of the second and third step and adjust the third step:

**fiori launchpad loads component (component.js)**

**load ui5 resources**

**...** **(other steps remain as with a stand alone ui5 application)**

because if the application is embedded in the fiori launchpad it gets directly invoked by the fiori launchpad via it's component.js.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..one more doubt ,when resources will get loaded in case of Fiori launchpad embedded UI5 application?

Comment: after the fiori launchpad loaded the application's component.

Answer (score 2):

#### Stand Alone

1. index.html
2. component.js
3. manifest.js
4. main view
5. main controller

#### Fiori

Fiori don't need index.html

1. component.js
2. manifest.js
3. main view
4. main controller